# Ordinal logistic regression how it differs from logistic regression?

Tags: machine-learning

I am sure this question may not be in the brilliant category. But Somehow to learn machine learning i may start with stupid question. So, please.

***I understood the terms of regressions partially.***

The regression essentially give the idea of the relationship between the dependent and independent variables.

If the dependent variable is continuous and if you see the linear relation between dependent and independent, then linear regression is a way to go.

A slight change now. If the dependent value could be something like Binary value (Y/N), ie: the output value is binomial distribution, then logistic regression is a way to go that which demands non linear relationship between dependent and independent.

So far..Please correct me if i am wrong.

**Now my question is with respect to ordinal logistic regression.**

I have started looking at the below link for reference

https://statistics.laerd.com/spss-tutorials/ordinal-regression-using-spss-statistics.php

Where it is mentioned that " ***It can be considered as either a generalisation of multiple linear regression or as a generalisation of binomial logistic regression***".

Could someone help me understand this above statement with examples?

Comment: Rather downvoting, pls educate me with the reason. Ideally the downvoting should be associated with it. It is something like endless pain without knowing the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Logistic regression can be considered as an extension of linear regression. But instead of predicting continuous variables, it predicts discrete variables by introducing the computation of an activation function. So, you are asked to produce a discriminatory function that based on X you produce a function that outputs **f: [1,2, ..., k]** where k is the number of classes that your problem presents. Now X can be composed of features that are both continuous or discrete. It does not matter, just make sure you apply pre-processing to them.

The base case for logistic regression is finding the decision boundary that divides two classes. But in order to add more classes, you have to implement another approach. There are several: softmax (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function), one-vs-all (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification), etc.

Finally, answering your question about **ordinal logistic regression** is an extension of logistic regression. But considers the order of the output variables such as in the case of a test. Take a look online for examples.